# neo4j 2.0 M3 logger not found

Tags: java, logging, neo4j

Found a way to do transaction logs here:

https://gist.github.com/psuman/3118371

The code I have moved here:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.event.TransactionData;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.event.TransactionEventHandler;

public class WarehouseTransactionEventHandler  implements TransactionEventHandler<String> {
private static Logger log = Logger
        .getLogger(WarehouseTransactionEventHandler.class);

public void afterCommit(TransactionData data, String state) {

    Iterable<Node> createdNodes = data.createdNodes();
    for(Node n: createdNodes) {
        log.info("AfterCommit ########: created node:" + n.getId());

    }


}

public void afterRollback(TransactionData data, String state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public String beforeCommit(TransactionData data) throws Exception {
    Iterable<Node> createdNodes = data.createdNodes();
    for(Node n: createdNodes) {
        log.info("BeforeCommit ######: created node:" + n.getId());

    }

    return null;
  }


}
```

However, it can't find the Logger object which is supposed to be in org.neo4j.server.logger when I add it as an import.  All I can find in the server-api-2.0.0-M03.jar library are helpers, plugins, or rest.  I am using neo4j 2.0 M3 Enterprise.  Any suggestions are appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is not in the database lib files

What you need to do is either add it to your maven pom or download it here

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j.app/neo4j-server/2.0.0-M03